# call bootstrap modal from a function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to get a modal working but i don't seem to get the right direction

This the function

```
function operateFormatter(value, row, index) {
            return [
                '<a class="info btn btn-warning btn-xs" title="Editar" id="bt" data-unique-id="',row.id,'" data-toggle="myModal" data-target="#myModal',row.id,'">',
                '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>',
                '</a>',
                ''<a href="#myModal" class="danger btn btn-danger btn-xs" title="Remover" id="bt" data-unique-id="',row.id,'" data-toggle="myModal" data-target="#myModal',row.id,'">',                    '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>',
                '</a>'
            ].join('');
        }
```

And i want to cal my modal from that function

```
 function removeItem(index, row){
             var id_itens = JSON.stringify(row.id_itens);
             $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
```

But nothing shows....any help?

UPDATE
All contente of this page

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Itens Registados</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/style_no_image.css" type="text/css"  />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-table.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-editable.css">
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            #bt {
                margin-left: 20px;
            }

            th.alinhado{
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="left">
                <label><a href="http://www.esmaior.pt/agrupamento/">ESMAIOR- Gestão Biblioteca</a></label>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <label><a href="logout.php?logout=true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i> Sair</a></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <?php include 'menu_admin.php'; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h3>Visualização e Edição de Registos</h3>
            <table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-striped"
                   data-toggle="table"
                   data-pagination="true"
                   data-search="true"
                   data-show-refresh="true"
                   data-show-toggle="true"
                   data-show-columns="true"
                   data-toolbar="#toolbar"
                   data-url='pdoGetItens.php'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="id_itens" class="hidden">ID</th>
                        <th data-field="nome" data-editable="true" class="alinhado">Nome</th>
                        <th data-field="descricao" data-editable="true" class="alinhado">Descrição</th>
                        <th data-field="tipo" data-editable="true" class="alinhado" data-align="center">Tipo</th>
                        <th data-field="estado" data-editable="true" class="alinhado" data-align="center">Estado</th>
                        <th data-field="data" data-editable="true" class="alinhado" data-align="center">Data</th>
                        <th data-field="quantidade" data-editable="true" class="alinhado" data-align="center">Quantidade</th>
                        <th data-field="operate" data-formatter="operateFormatter" data-events="operateEvents" class="alinhado" data-align="center">Opções</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                         <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Atenção!</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnDelteYes" href="#">Sim</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Não</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-table-pt-PT.js"></script>
        <script>
            function operateFormatter(value, row, index) {
                return [
                    "<a class='info btn btn-warning btn-xs' title='Editar' id='bt' data-unique-id='"+row.id+"' data-toggle='myModal' data-target='#myModal"+row.id+"'>",                
                    "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i>",
                    "</a>",
                    "<a href='#myModal' class='danger btn btn-danger btn-xs' title='Remover' id='bt' data-unique-id='"+row.id+"' data-toggle='myModal' data-target='#myModal'"+row.id+"'>",
                    "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i>",
                    "</a>"
                ].join('');
            }

            function removeItem(row){
             var id_itens = JSON.stringify(row.id_itens);
             $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE 2

```
<script>
        function operateFormatter(value, row, index) {
            return [
                "<a class='info btn btn-warning btn-xs' title='Editar' id='bt'>",                
                "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i>",
                "</a>",
                '<a class="remove btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="#myModal" title="Remover">',
                '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>',
                '</a>'      
            ].join(' ');
        }

         window.operateEvents = {
        'click .like': function (e, value, row, index) {
            alert('You click like icon, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
            console.log(value, row, index);
        },
        'click .edit': function (e, value, row, index) {
            alert('You click edit icon, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
            console.log(value, row, index);
        },
        'click .remove': function (e, value, row, index) {
            $('#myModal').modal('show').find('.modal-body #nome').val(JSON.stringify(row.nome));
            $('#myModal').modal('show').find('.modal-body #id_itens').val(JSON.stringify(row.id_itens));
        }
    }
```

e o meu modal devia chamar a função

```
 <form onsubmit="submitForm('#myForm'); return false;" id='myForm'>
```

Function

```
function submitForm(formId) {
            var user_id = $('input[id="id_itens"]').val();
            console.log(user_id);}
```

mas  nada acontece

Comment: Provide us a fiddle please

Comment: Your code seems to have syntax errors, did you checked your console ? Or it may be a typo in your snippet `''<a href=` ?

Comment: I'm making one wait a little please...thank for helping

Comment: I can't get it to work sinc it's using my php pdo file, the main file is in http://esmaior.pt/biblioteca/getItems.php, there you can check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your code more clearly so we can understand better.

For now I can tell you have several errors in the construction of return.

i think its work better

```
function operateFormatter(value, row, index) {
    return [
        "<a class='info btn btn-warning btn-xs' title='Editar' id='bt' data-unique-id='"+row.id+"' data-toggle='myModal' data-target='#myModal"+row.id+"''>",                
        "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i>",
        "</a>",
        "<a href='#myModal' class='danger btn btn-danger btn-xs' title='Remover' id='bt' data-unique-id='"+row.id+"' data-toggle='myModal' data-target='#myModal"+row.id+"'>",
        "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i>",
        "</a>"
    ].join('');
}
```

Comment: Hi Deivi, thanks, i have updated with your code but still not opening the modal, when the page load i have this url http://esmaior.pt/biblioteca/getItems.php when i hit the button  nothing happens

Comment: use firefox with firebug plugin, it show me error "empty string passed to getElementById.

Comment: looking your source-code i found a little error
`<div class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
        </div>`
maybe u forget to close the tag <div>

Comment: Deduzo que sejas brasileiro, então vou facilitar pra nós, esse erro da div não fechar pode estar causando todo o problema ou não,  se tu inspencionar o codigo fonte do botão ele esta assim
`<a class="info btn btn-warning btn-xs" title="Editar" id="bt" data-unique-id="undefined" data-toggle="myModal" data-target="#myModalundefined" '=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>`
veja que tem um erro ali no final da div, acredito que alguma coisa que você esta tentando construir dinamicamente está falhando

Comment: I don't have any getElementById...strange

Comment: Deivi...mas não é esse que quero chamar, é o de baixo  "<a href='#myModal' class='danger btn btn-danger btn-xs' title='Remover' id='bt' data-unique-id='"+row.id+"' data-toggle='myModal' data-target='#myModal'"+row.id+"'>",
                    "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i>",
                    "</a>"

Comment: o problema deve estar em chamar pelo id mas não estou a ver

Comment: no firefox aparece-me Cadeia de caracteres vazia enviada para getElementById(). quando clico em remover

Comment: existe erro de código que esta fazendo estourar nesse javascript, tens que revisar seu código e retirar todos esses errinhos que ficam na construção. se quiseres editar teu post aqui e colocar mais código para vermos mais detalhes pode ajudar

Comment: vou pôr a página toda para ver o que se passa, já ando nisto há dias e não saio dessa porcaria

Comment: olha como esta o codigo do botão na pagina
`<a href="#myModal" class="danger btn btn-danger btn-xs" title="Remover" id="bt" data-unique-id="undefined" data-toggle="myModal" data-target="#myModal" undefined'=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>`
 o ultimo elemento que você coloca na div esta ficando com problema igual ao botão anterior. ele esta ficando 'undefined' ou seja, você tem erros nos valores passados para a construção dos botões da modal. 
pelo que vejo a variavel row que você usa está indo vazia.  não sei aonde você chama a função operateFormatter(...)

Comment: já pus o código todo da página, operateFormatter(...) está na tabela, no último <th>, é onde estão os botões para ação do usuário

Comment: ta, arruma a aspa sobrando (veja a edição que fiz na minha resposta) e abaixo da linha 
             var id_itens = JSON.stringify(row.id_itens);
coloque console.log(row); para ver o que tem dentro da variavel, acredito que ela esteja em branco, veja no console do firefox se vai aparecer o print do console.log() ou se vai aparecer somente 'undefined'

Comment: Ja vejo isso daqui a pouco...hora de almoço em portugal . Obrigado e ja volto

Comment: Vi e revi...está melhor agora estou feito não consigo chamar a função para remover..vê o update

Comment: acho que se você trocar (dentro da modal) o type do botão "sim" para submit ao inves de button você vai conseguir o que precisa